# Difference between clearing cache in Internal memory & removable memory in android

Tags: android, caching, memory

### I know we can cache files in android

- Internal-memory(phone memory)
- Removable memory(SD-CARD)

***So i know android does housekeeping operations and clears the cache memory as needed.***

### Questions

1. When the android will clear the cache memory in internal memory &
   when in removable memory ?
2. Will it wait for internal memory or Removable memory to get full and
   then clear it ?
3. Is there a certain threshold value for cache used by a particular
   application in internal and external memory?
4. Is Cache in internal and external are one and same apart from where
   they are located ?